# Aws IAM user permission to specific region and to a particular server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want to setup permissions for newly created IAM user so that the user will be able to access  only particular ec2 instance in a given region.

For instance. I have 3 ec2 instances running in aws us-east i.e N. Virginia
I want restrict user for rebooting, starting and stopping to only 1 ec2 server

I wrote a policy like below but its not working. I am not sure what i am missing here.

{

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/i-d4f1b83a"
    }
]
```

}

Thanks for your Help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? How are they making the call (via the Console or API)? What error are they receiving?

Comment: I am trying to setup IAM user for aws managment console here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy works. I tested it and successfully used it to start only specific instances.

Some things to note:

- In your **Resource** section, be sure to substitute `accountid` for your own 12-digit Account ID (available in your Billing/Account page)
- IAM only supports a [limited number of resource-specific API calls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html). Stop, Start and Reboot are included, but the Describe calls are not resource-specific.

IAM policies can be tested via the **Simulate Policy** link next to a policy definition, which links to the **[Policy Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UsingPolicySimulatorGuide/iam-policy-simulator-guide.html)**. This is a great tool for debugging permission issues.

Comment: Hey John thanks for reply. I am getting following error for the ec2 oprations "An error occurred fetching instance data: You are not authorized to perform this operation." even after putting my real accountid.

Comment: Which command did you call? Try the Policy Simulator to test the policy, or decode the encoded error message returned by using the "aws sts decode-authorization-message" command.

Comment: John, It is resolved now. I did something like below.

Comment: Also Can we limit a user for cloudwatch service in particular region?

Comment: Yes, you can limit CloudWatch permissions based on region. Please create another Question with more details if you'd like some help.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this which helped me. But still All the resources are visible to that IAM user which i actually don't want. Any further answers would be a great help.

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:accountid:instance/instance-id",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You cannot "hide" selective resources. Either they can describe them all, or describe none. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html